# how to fix circular import in django?

Tags: python, django, rest, api, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create an api that uploads an image with an email to the database. But I'm getting an error "raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))" Is the problem in my urls.py?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnfuG.png

This is how my structure looks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEskp.png

This is the error

### for urls.py-

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('user.urls')),
    path('api/',include('api_test.urls'))
    # path('articles/',include('articles.urls'))

]
```

### for api_test/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path,include
from django.conf import settings
from . import views

from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('image_test',views.api_test,base_name='image_test')

urlpatterns = [
    # path('/',views.api_test),
    path('',include(routers.url)),


]
```

### for views.py

```
class api_test(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = fineDB.objects.all()
    serializer_class = fineSerializer

##for serializers.py

from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import fineDB

class fineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None,use_url=True)
    class Meta:
        model = fineDB
        fields = {'email','image'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably get the urls from `router`, not `routers`.
At the same time you don't need both the router and the urlpatterns in that file. You can import the router and mount it's `router.urls` in `urls.py`.

```
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('image_test',views.api_test,base_name='image_test')

urlpatterns = [
    # path('/',views.api_test),
    path('',include(router.urls)),    # <-


]
```

Comment: doesn't work. Says 'DefaultRouter' object has no attribute 'url'

Comment: Ah, there was a misspelling there as well. I've updated the code example.

Comment: ah. Stupid me. Thanks alot. This was it